# Export Universal framework for distribution

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

i have created a framework

Now if reveal it in finder,
It have 2 directory having framework

1. iphoneos
2. iphone simmulater

Now i create an app, and drag my framework from iphoneos directory, it run fine in iphone device but gives error in simmulater.

similarely if i drag framework from iphone simulater it work fine in simmulater  but give error in device.

Please how to export both directory framework in a combine.
i have try to run script of lipo using aggreation target, but it fails
please guide proper steps.

Answer (score 1):

You can add similar script to your build settings `Build Phase` tab as `Run Script`

```
# debug sim
xcrun xcodebuild -project myFramework.xcodeproj -target myFramework -configuration Debug -sdk iphonesimulator ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO

# release sim
xcrun xcodebuild -project myFramework.xcodeproj -target myFramework -configuration Release -sdk iphonesimulator ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO

# debug ios
xcrun xcodebuild -project myFramework.xcodeproj -target myFramework -configuration Debug -sdk iphoneos ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO

# release ios
xcrun xcodebuild -project myFramework.xcodeproj -target myFramework -configuration Release -sdk iphoneos ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO

mkdir -p build/Release-Universal/myFramework.framework
cp -r build/Debug-iphonesimulator/myFramework.framework/* build/Release-Universal/myFramework.framework/
rm build/Release-Universal/myFramework.framework/myFramework

# lipo
lipo -create build/Release-iphoneos/myFramework.framework/myFramework build/Release-iphonesimulator/myFramework.framework/myFramework -output build/Release-Universal/myFramework.framework/myFramework
```